# Can I delete a model instance using a for loop inside a Django template?

Tags: django-templates, django-views

Using this example below, I am trying to figure out a way to have the "delete" button delete the entry.

```
VIEWS.PY

latest_entries=Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]



TEMPLATE.HTML

{% for entry in latest_entries %}
   entry.name <div class="delete">delete</div>
   entry.price
   entry.picture
   entry.sellername

{% endfor %}
```

From reading Django docs, I understand that I can delete an object in my views by doing something like so:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
b.delete()
```

However I'm not sure how to link this in with my for loop in the template.

Can a delete a model instance from the for loop in my template or do I need to go another route to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and should not try due to security issues) delete a model instance from the template, you should communicate the action to a view and then delete it from the view.

One option is to use Javascript and send the request via AJAX. Then, recieve the call in a django url->view. A simple example of the view could look like this.

```
def delete_object(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      objeect_id = request.POST.get('object_id')
      deleted_entry = Entry.objects.get(id=object_id)
      deleted_entry.delete()
```

After reading your question again, I don't understand why you want to delete the object using a forloop. Is there an event that triggers the delete?, if the event is the user clicking a button, then the button should point to a Django url and then the url should point to the view.

Comment: Basically this is a storefront page that a seller can log in to.  What I want is to list all the items that the seller has posted for sale and give the seller the ability to delete any of those items.  Since I am using a for loop to display the items, I was thinking there would be a way to delete individual items. I don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: I am aware I can do as you have shown above, however I don't know how to do the javascript that goes along with it.  I was hoping there was a more Django-ish way.